# Search/Replace a custom marker with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

In a text string, I want to look for any occurence of [[mymarker-id]] and replace it with a custom html string:

```
'<div>id</div>'
```

For instance:

```
"this is a sample text [[mymarker-123_4Efd]] for illustration purpose"
```

would become

```
"this is a sample text <div>123_4Efd</div> for illustration purpose"
```

with id an 8 characters long string matching: ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){8}

I wish I could say I tried many things before asking, but I'm pretty bad with regexes

Comment: `(\[\[mymarker-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{8}\]\])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the 8-character long `Id` and replace the `Id` in your custom HTML with the captured text.

```
var marker = "this is a sample text [[mymarker-123_4Efd]] for illustration purpose"
marker.replace(/\[\[mymarker-(.{8})\]\]/, '<div>$1</div>')
```

Or if custom HTML is dynamically constructed:

```
var customHtml = '<div>id</div>';
var id = marker.match(/\[\[mymarker-(.{8})\]\]/)[1];
customHtml = customHtml.replace('id', id);
```

[**jsBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/UZUkuve/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\[\[mymarker\-([^\]]+)\]\]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str   = "this is a sample text [[mymarker-123_4Efd]] for illustration purpose";
var regex = /(\[\[mymarker\-)([^\]]+)\]\]/;
str = str.replace(regex, "<div>$2</div>");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var re = /\[\[mymarker-123_4Efd\]\]/gi;
    var str = "this is a sample text [[mymarker-123_4Efd]] for illustration purpose";
    var newstr = str.replace(re, "<div>123_4Efd</div>");
    console.log(newstr);
```

You must escape [ and ] symbols with backslashes